# Fabricjs: canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit in iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, canvas, fabricjs

While implementing Fabricjs, we have encountered a canvas memory limit error.
we have noticed that an older version of Fabric (1.3.0) merge all drawing in a single canvas thus keeping canvas memory consumption manageable, but in the latest version, every action lives in a separate canvas.
Is there a way in the latest version of Fabricjs to force all drawing and actions to apply only in the main canvas without creating secondary canvases

Please note that we have tried to deactivate the object cache without success:

fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to force objectCaching = false; and it worked.
`fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;`
Thanks.